# Drop Down List with class array on jsp

Tags: java, sorting, jsp

I need know, how to show in Drop Down list on a jsp, only one attribute of a arraylist of a class,i mean.

I have this class:

```js
public class Estacionamientos {
    private String nombreEstacionamiento;
    private int numeroTicket;
    private int precioEstacionamiento;

    public Estacionamientos() {      
    }

    public Estacionamientos(String nombreEstacionamiento, int numeroTicket, int precioEstacionamiento) {
        this.nombreEstacionamiento = nombreEstacionamiento;
        this.numeroTicket = numeroTicket;
        this.precioEstacionamiento = precioEstacionamiento;
    }

    public String getNombreEstacionamiento() {
        return nombreEstacionamiento;
    }

    public void setNombreEstacionamiento(String nombreEstacionamiento) {
        this.nombreEstacionamiento = nombreEstacionamiento;
    }

    public int getNumeroTicket() {
        return numeroTicket;
    }

    public void setNumeroTicket(int numeroTicket) {
        this.numeroTicket = (int) (Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1);
    }

    public int getPrecioEstacionamiento() {
        return precioEstacionamiento;
    }

    public void setPrecioEstacionamiento(int precioEstacionamiento) {
        this.precioEstacionamiento = precioEstacionamiento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Estacionamientos{" + "nombreEstacionamiento=" + nombreEstacionamiento + ", numeroTicket=" + numeroTicket + ", precioEstacionamiento=" + precioEstacionamiento + '}';
    }
```

this array

```js
public class ListarEstacionamientos {

    Estacionamientos est = new Estacionamientos();
    ArrayList<Estacionamientos> list = new ArrayList<Estacionamientos>() {
        {
            add(new Estacionamientos("Estación Central", 2000, est.getNumeroTicket()));
            add(new Estacionamientos("Mall Alameda", 2000, est.getNumeroTicket()));
            add(new Estacionamientos("Mall Providencia", 2000, est.getNumeroTicket()));
            add(new Estacionamientos("Aparcamiento Quinta Normal", 2000, est.getNumeroTicket()));
            add(new Estacionamientos("Estacionamiento Parque Arauco Maipú", 2000, est.getNumeroTicket()));
        }
    };  
   
}
```

but i dont know how to show only the attibute name of Estacionamientos in a drop down list on a JSP form...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to pass an array from the java to your jsp, run this code in the dropdown logic.

```
      <c:forEach items="${yourArray}" var="firstArr"> 
          <c:forEach items="${firstArr}" var="innerArr"> // firstVar will hold your object array
             <c:out value="${innerArr.field1}" /> // on iterating the object array 
          </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
```